# Coulomb Scale - Two equally charged Balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

I got a task involving a coulomb scale:

> Two equally charged balls (m=16g) are hanging silently on two ropes with Length $L=1.6$ m. Both ropes are installed at the same point and create relative to the vertical line an angle of $\theta=13.4$°. What is the charge of each ball in microCoulomb.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CmOw.png
Above image showing the setup and the below image is a geometric presentation to explain why $F_c/F_g = \tan(13.4°)$.
My issue is, why is that solution valid?

1. The length of $F_g$ might not be the same as the vertical line until the point between the two balls.
2. Theta would only be present if half of $F_c$ would be considered right?

I just seem to not be able to understand how those forces can be combined to apply the tangents rule. I understand the math part and how to achieve a solution, but I just do not understand the geometric optimizations so the tangents rule applies.

I created an additional picture with things colorized that confuse me (alpha instead of theta):https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecgqI.png

1. The bottom horizontal line is not the same as the red line, so its not the same $F_c$ in my opinion.
2. There is no reason for orange line being the same length as green, hence the deviation of $F_c$ could cause a differen angle then theta ($\alpha$ in this picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you did not understand the addition of F vectors.
One chooses an arbitrary length for mg,(it has nothing to do with length of strings or other vertical lines)  the length of Fc is then the result, so that mg and Fc together combine to go in the direction of the string. Than you have to calculate the distance r of the two charges and put them in Coulombs law.
The angle between mg and Fc is the same as the angle of the string to the vertical. The length you draw for Fc has nothing to do with the distance, only the angle to mg and the string matter.

Comment: and the angle has to be the same, because otherwise they could  not cancel each other out right?

Comment: " cancel each other out " I would not say so;  better:  add together to give the direction of the string

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now